# How do you render videos, after deployment to Vercel? "Unable to Play Media"

Tags: video, next.js, vercel

I am trying to use a video as my webpage background on a next.js 13 / react app

& I am getting back "unable to play media" on the webpage, and within the Vercel Source Output.

My video works great in a local environment, I did have to use Github LFS not sure if that may be why?

I am serving the video from 'public' folder, it is a 200 mb+ mp4.

[[image: Live]]

[image: Local]```

Expected the video to render and be full screen..

My video code

```
 <div className="z-10">
            <div className="overlay"></div>
            <video id="videoBG" className="" autoPlay loop >
            <source src="Water.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
            </video>
        </div>
```

Comment: Does the video file exist at same place as HTML file?

Comment: Change the `src` to `/Water.mp4`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving.

Comment: It resided in the public folder - for some reason, vercel wouldn't render locally pushed videos, though loads videos that come from an online host without any issues.  I even tried shrinking the video, to 20 Mb, though that was the most I could shrink it. Locally pushing a video that's under 10Mb may work, though I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, for anyone else who runs into this issue. Vercel doesn't work with github lfs! I ended up hosting the video via a 3rd party (I used cloudflare) and imported it via url.

UPDATE

**
Cloudflare stream doesn't allow inline css alterations, so was unable to efficiently set it as a background video, as to it was stuck to a set aspect size, and refused to cover entire viewport at certain screen sizes.

I fixed this by using Vimeo Video hosting instead, though had to get a standard account. Vimeo worked fantastic for this use case.